# No taxes calculating in fresh magento 2 shop with migrated data

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, tax, taxes

I installed a fresh magento 2.3.5 enterprise, and migrated the data and products from a magento 1 shop with the official migration tool. However, there are no taxes calculating:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change "**Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Price Display Settings -> Display Product Prices In Catalog**" to "**Include Tax**"